# Activar icono en menu dinamico html

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Buenas tardes tengo un pagina principal con un menú dinámico y iconos, necesito que al dar click sobre el icono me redireccione a otra interfaz.

```html
<div class="content-menu">

            
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-home icon1"></span><h4 class="text1">Inicio </h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-film-play icon2"></span><h4 class="text2">Cursos</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-store icon3"></span><h4 class="text3">Productos</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-picture icon4"></span><h4 class="text4">usuario</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-briefcase icon5"></span><h4 class="text5">Foro</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-license icon6"></span><h4 class="text6">Blog</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-bubble icon7"></span><h4 class="text7">Mensajes</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-envelope icon8"></span><h4 class="text8">Contactos</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-question-circle icon9"></span><h4 class="text9">Nosotros</h4></li>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A que te refieres, que al presionar dicho icono te lleve a otra pagina?
Si es asi tienes que agregar la etiqueta a href="" Por ejemplo:

```
<li><a href="contact.html"><span class="lnr lnr-home icon1"></span><h4 class="text1">Inicio </h4></a></li>
```

Este te llevaria al archivo contact.html, cambia el contact.html por el nombre de tu archivo o url

Comment: Mucha gracias no habia ubicado en el href